# Hash param and merchant salt are not genraterate payU

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payu

I need to integrate payU payment gateway in my android app. But when app is trying to to get hash key it gives me error saying that

Hash param is missing

In demo app there are two option to generate hash

if(null == salt) 
        generateHashFromServer(mPaymentParams);
    else 
        generateHashFromSDK(mPaymentParams, intent.getStringExtra(PayuConstants.SALT));

In demo app there are note saying that hash key generation should be done on server side

so I am passing salt as null

but Now the question is Which server url I have to use to generate hash? Demo app is using this

https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/tag/s4.3.6c6m1.0.4

Comment: You should have a server to serve the android request.  This is the sample code for php server.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ToBwKkXbZuZ2xPdEt5SGZCUHM/view